# Invalid Sender Faucet

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumjs

i have a problem with sender address, please help me.

```js
const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
const { generateErrorResponse } = require('../helpers/generate-response')
const { validateCaptcha } = require('../helpers/captcha-helper')
const { debug } = require('../helpers/debug')

module.exports = function (app) {
    const config = app.config
    const web3 = app.web3

    const messages = {
        INVALID_CAPTCHA: 'Invalid captcha',
        INVALID_ADDRESS: 'Invalid address',
        TX_HAS_BEEN_MINED_WITH_FALSE_STATUS: 'Transaction has been mined, but status is false',
        TX_HAS_BEEN_MINED: 'Tx has been mined',
    }

    app.post('/', async function(request, response) {
        const isDebug = app.config.debug
        debug(isDebug, "REQUEST:")
        debug(isDebug, request.body)
        const recaptureResponse = request.body["g-recaptcha-response"]
        if (!recaptureResponse) {
            const error = {
                message: messages.INVALID_CAPTCHA,
            }
            return generateErrorResponse(response, error)
        }

        let captchaResponse
        try {
            captchaResponse = await validateCaptcha(app, recaptureResponse)
        } catch(e) {
            return generateErrorResponse(response, e)
        }
        const receiver = request.body.receiver
        if (await validateCaptchaResponse(captchaResponse, receiver, response)) {
            await sendPOAToRecipient(web3, receiver, response, isDebug)
        }
    });

    app.get('/health', async function(request, response) {
        let balanceInWei
        let balanceInEth
        const address = config.Ethereum[config.environment].account
        try {
            balanceInWei = await web3.eth.getBalance(address)
            balanceInEth = await web3.utils.fromWei(balanceInWei, "ether")
        } catch (error) {
            return generateErrorResponse(response, error)
        }

        const resp = {
            address,
            balanceInWei: balanceInWei,
            balanceInEth: Math.round(balanceInEth)
        }
        response.send(resp)
    });

    async function validateCaptchaResponse(captchaResponse, receiver, response) {
        if (!captchaResponse || !captchaResponse.success) {
            generateErrorResponse(response, {message: messages.INVALID_CAPTCHA})
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    async function sendPOAToRecipient(web3, receiver, response, isDebug) {
        let senderPrivateKey = config.Ethereum[config.environment].privateKey
        const privateKeyHex = Buffer.from(senderPrivateKey, 'hex')
        if (!web3.utils.isAddress(receiver)) {
            return generateErrorResponse(response, {message: messages.INVALID_ADDRESS})
        }
        
        const gasPrice = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'gwei')
        const gasPriceHex = web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice)
        const gasLimitHex = web3.utils.toHex(config.Ethereum.gasLimit)
        const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(config.Ethereum[config.environment].account)
        const nonceHex = web3.utils.toHex(nonce)
        const BN = web3.utils.BN
        const ethToSend = web3.utils.toWei(new BN(config.Ethereum.milliEtherToTransfer), "milliether")
        const rawTx = {
          nonce: nonceHex,
          gasPrice: gasPriceHex,
          gasLimit: gasLimitHex,
          to: receiver, 
          value: ethToSend,
          data: '0x00'
        }

        const tx = new EthereumTx(rawTx, {'chainId':'1951'})
        tx.sign(privateKeyHex)

        const serializedTx = tx.serialize()

        let txHash
        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
        .on('transactionHash', (_txHash) => {
            txHash = _txHash
        })
        .on('receipt', (receipt) => {
            debug(isDebug, receipt)
            if (receipt.status == '0x1') {
                return sendRawTransactionResponse(txHash, response)
            } else {
                const error = {
                    message: messages.TX_HAS_BEEN_MINED_WITH_FALSE_STATUS,
                }
                return generateErrorResponse(response, error);
            }
        })
        .on('error', (error) => {
            return generateErrorResponse(response, error)
        });
    }

    function sendRawTransactionResponse(txHash, response) {
        const successResponse = {
            code: 200, 
            title: 'Success', 
            message: messages.TX_HAS_BEEN_MINED,
            txHash: txHash
        }
        
        response.send({
            success: successResponse
        })
    }
}
```

Please Help

Comment: You put the code but you don't mention what is your problem with it. Could you add more details of the problem you are having?

Comment: The problem is when you want to request a token, the server issues an error that is Invalid Sender

Comment: Can you paste the error stack trace?

Comment: { Error: Returned error: invalid sender
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/root/poa-faucet/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at /root/poa-faucet/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:300:36
    at /root/poa-faucet/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:124:13
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) data: null }